# deserializar Json con llave numérica y en multi-nivel

Tags: c#, json

Error al tratar de obtener el valor de "valor_cuota". Lo que he indagado es que la Key del json es un "1" y por tal un entero no funciona, luego entré a buscar como convertir esa Key probé con `Dictionary<get, set>` sin resultados, pues el código que encuentro no lo comprendo bien para adaptarlo al mio. también probé con `List<array>` pero no fue existoso por el mismo motivo anterior, lo que encuentro no logro adaptarlo a mi Json ya que todos son de "2 niveles" y el mío parece tener 4. *Nota: lbl1, lbl5, lbl6 y lbl7 son labels de webforms.*

```
protected void DeserializeJSon(string StrJSon)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer Deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    desJson_RootObject JsonObj = new desJson_RootObject();
    JsonObj = Deserializer.Deserialize<desJson_RootObject>(StrJSon);

    //ROOTOBJECT
    lbl1.Text = "success:: " + JsonObj.success.ToString();

    //DATA
    lbl5.Text = "val_cuo:: " + JsonObj.data.val_cuo.ToString();
    lbl6.Text = "fec_lim:: " + JsonObj.data.fec_lim.ToString();
    //AMORTI

    lbl7.Text = "Amorti:: " + JsonObj.data.amorti.a.valor_cuota.ToString();
}
[DataContract]
public class desJson_RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "success")]
    public bool success { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public desJson_Data data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class desJson_Data
{
    [DataMember(Name = "val_cuo")]
    public int val_cuo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "fec_lim")]
    public string fec_lim { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "amorti")]
    public desJson_Amorti amorti { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class desJson_Amorti
{
    [DataMember(Name = "1")]
    public desJson__1 _1 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class desJson__1
{
    [DataMember(Name = "position")]
    public int position { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "valor_cuota")]
    public int valor_cuota { get; set; }       
}
```

JSON::

```
{
    "success":true,
    "action":"cotizacion de cuota",
    "message":"Cotizaci\u00f3n exitosa",
    "code":1001,
    "data":{
        "val_cuo":1940660,
        "fec_lim":"24-12-2018",
        "amorti":{
            "1":{
                "position":1,
                "valor_cuota":1940660,
                "intereses":0,
                "capital":1940660,
                "saldo":559340
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error generado] 
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: los niveles no tienes nada que ver, el problema es una incorrecta definicion del json, deberias usar array y no propiedades para definir valores que varian en cantidad. Debria ser `"amorti": [ {"position":1, "valor_cuota":1940660, ...},  {"position":2, "valor_cuota":2040500, ...}]` si en `amorti` usas el `[]` defines un array de elementos

Comment: Hola y gracias, por tu comentario, el problema es que así viene el json desde el webservice.